# How to replace extra spaces in text file with comma in linux

Tags: linux

my text file has 3 or more than 3 spaces, now I want to replace the 3 or more than 3 spaces with a comma and it should not replace if the file has less than 3 spaces

```
ex:
input:
a b  3   c     d      6        9
output:
a b,3,c,d,6,9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/ {3,}/,/g' file
a b  3,c,d,6,9
```

The `-r` flag instructs the `sed` to use the [extended regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) syntax which we need for the `{min,max}` interval operator in the `s///` [search/replace command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions). With it we say: for each occurrence (note the `g`, or global flag in the end) of the space character which is repeated 3 or more times (no upper limit), replace it with `,`. Pass through all other characters.